# How to disable APC caching in PHP file

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to disable apc caching in a php file? By means of a php set function of some sort?

I want to disable caching for Magento's Indexer.php file so it doesn't use APC caching.

Comment: There's just `apc.enabled` which can only be set at the .ini/.conf level. You could try ugly hacks like a `<FilesMatch "!apcdisabled.php">php_value apc.enabled 1</FilesMatch`

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall the module, or just disable it Adding the following line to the

.htaccess file: `php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off`

Also keep in mind that Indexer.php will be not Cached by APC if you run it via Cron job !